# URL rewriting Issue with html pages in IIS6 asp.net (2.0) application

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis, rewrite

I am using URL rewriting for asp.net (2.0)application on Server 2003 with IIS 6

Website url example mywebsite.com and mywebsite.com/blog.

mywebsite.com runnig with.aspx and .html pages
Database: SQL Server 2005.

mywebsite.com/blog has wordpress deployed
Database: MySQl 5.6

**httpd.conf Details:**

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blog/index.php?p=$1 [NC,L]
```

The main problem is that while using httpd.conf rewrite code, only .html pages are not working. *"**getting “Oops, The Page You Are Looking For Cannot Be Located**"*

Comment: I think httpd.conf is an Apache feature not IIS. Are you sure your website is running on IIS and not Apache ? .html file doesn't work in mywebsite.com/ and mywebsite.com/blog/ ?

Comment: ISAPI_Rewrite3 tool can be used for this and It will create http. conf file where the user can put the above mentioned for httpd. conf .html files stopped working while using it.

Comment: Does .html file doesn't work in mywebsite.com/ and mywebsite.com/blog/  ? If you keep your httpd.conf but empty, does .html file work ?

Comment: Yes I when remove code from httpd.conf then .html files works for mywebsite.com/ and mywebsite.com/blog/ is (WordPress) site, I am using url_rewrite module for WordPress blog with custom pages .

Comment: Did you tried to remove `RewriteBase /` and change `blog` to `/blog` ? Should the rule be applied to / or only to /blog/ ?

Comment: No Luck tried the same still getting Oops, _The Page You Are Looking For Cannot Be Located_

Comment: Maybe you can check the logs for more informations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below method solved my problem. Now i am able to browse:

*mywebsite.com - .aspx*

*mywebsite.com - .html*

*mywebsite.com/blog - .php*

**File http.conf:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} blog
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
```